# How to see what app initiated the call using Universal Links from website?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

There is an iOS app, let's call it **"App A"** that signs documents. Using deep linking (universal links) a partner app, let's call it **"App B"** opens this app, **"App A"** signs the document and then **"App B"** opens and show success message.

Let's call this process ***"app-to-app-to-app"***.

Now, there's also a website, let's call it **"Website A"** that acts like **"App B"** i.e. opens **"App A"** to sign a document. Using the previous method it is possible to open the **"App A"** but it seems not to be possible to return to the initiator, in this case **"Website A"** to show the success message and/or continue the service flow.

Let's call the process ***"web-to-app-to-web"***.

It seems that the **"App B"** cannot tell what app summoned it in the ***"web-to-app-to-web"*** scenario.

What do you think? Is there a solution to this? What am I missing? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two cases :

1. Use web-inspector to check what is happening in background.
2. For "web-to-app-to-web" , it will be in parts
   2.1 For web-app , send a json from web view which can be handled by           webview delegates.
   2.2 For app to web , use api integration to send data to webview to open the webpage in web view accordingly.

I hope this helps.